# Is my disk safe after a SysRq reboot?

Tags: linux, fedora, sysrq

Every time I do a SysRq S-U-B sequence (I have tried others, too, but I suppose these are the commands that matter) my system does a full hard drive scan on the subsequent boot. Unfortunately sometimes it is the best I can do because there's a fault in a proprierary firmware I need and when it crashes I am unable to turn off my computer normally due to hung applications responding not even to SIGKILL.

I thought the whole point of the sync – unmount – reboot was to prevent any damage to the data, but seeing the system's need to check the hard drive every single time indicates suspicion something's not right. Am I harming it? Is there something I should do differently?